# Asserting attributes on a capybara object

Tags: attributes, find, selector, capybara, assert

I am currently working with capybara for integration testing and as part of our testing framework.  I am running into an issue that I cannot seem to find a solution to.  So the scenario is this, I initially do a find for a tbody element. I get the object back and thats all well and good.  The problem that I am facing is that there is a point in my testing where I need to assert that the css class of the tbody object that I am working with has changed.  Every method I have tried so far fails.  The code looks something like this:

```
@element = find('tbody')

--tbody css selecor changes to '.is-edit-post'

@element.find('.is-edit-post')
```

I am trying to assert that the capybara object has that css selector.  I have also tried the following:

```
@element.has_css('.is-edit-post')

@element.assert_selector('.is-edit-post')
```

Now, I dont fully understand how the #find method works and what exactly it returns.  At this point, I am speculating that since the tbody object didnt have that css selector at the time it was found and returned by the #find method, that this is why it is returning false or throwing an exception saying it is not found.

Anyone have any ideas on how I can get at the attribute of that capybara object if the attributes for that object change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a long while since I posted this question, but I think that the answer I was looking for in this case was:
`@element[:class].include? 'is-edit-post'`

Or if the element didnt update, I would need to grab it again and then check the class:

`find('tbody')[:class].include? 'is-edit-post'`

In any case, I got around this problem long ago.